# Python - "'NoneType' object is not iterable" error assigning values to a def in a loop

Tags: python, nonetype

I have been looking all over the place and I don't understand why I keep getting the same error. I have read that it has something to do with 'return' but it does not makes sense to me.

```
Traceback:
  File "/tmp/vmuser_mlgewmyusy/main.py", line 47, in daysBetweenDates
    new_year,new_month,new_day=nextDay(new_year,new_month,new_day)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Code:

```
def nextDay(year, month, day):
if month!=12:
    if month==1 or month==3 or month==5 or month==7 or month==8 or month==10:
        if day!=31:
            return year,month,day+1
        else:
            return year,month+1,1
    elif month==4 or month==6 or month==9 or month==11:
        if day!= 30:
            return year,month,day+1
        else:
            return year,month+1,1
    elif month==2:
        if day!= 28:
            return year,month,day+1
        else:
            return year,month+1,1 
    elif month==22:
        if day!= 29:
            return year,month,day+1
        else:
            return year,month+1,1
    else:
        if day!= 31:
            return year,month,day+1
        else:
            return year+1,1,1

def daysBetweenDates(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):
    i=0
    new_year,new_month,new_day=year1-100,month1-100,day1-100
    if year1==year2 and month1==month2 and day1==day2:
        return 0
    while new_year!=year2 and new_month!=month2 and new_day!=day2:
        if i==0:
            `new_year,new_month,new_day`=year1+100,month1+100,day1+100
        i+=1
        new_year,new_month,new_day=nextDay(new_year,new_month,new_day)
    return i

# Test routine

def test():
    test_cases = [((2012,1,1,2012,2,28), 58), 
                  ((2012,1,1,2012,3,1), 60),
                  ((2011,6,30,2012,6,30), 366),
                  ((2011,1,1,2012,8,8), 585 ),
                  ((1900,1,1,1999,12,31), 36523)]
    for (args, answer) in test_cases:
        result = daysBetweenDates(*args)
        if result != answer:
            print "Test with data:", args, "failed"
            print 'ANSWER = {}'.format(answer)
            print 'RESULT = {}'.format(result)
        else:
            print "Test case passed!"

test()
```

I want to assign a new value to 'new_year,new_month,new_day' every times the loop iterates.

Comment: Could you show how you call these functions?

Comment: Why don't you use datetime lib?

Comment: It is for a course, i cant use any library

Answer (score 0):

I added these two print lines into the `daysBetweenDates` function:

```
...
if i==0:
        new_year,new_month,new_day=year1+100,month1+100,day1+100
    i+=1
    print(new_month)
    print(nextDay(new_year,new_month,new_day))
    new_year,new_month,new_day=nextDay(new_year,new_month,new_day)
...
```

I try this input `daysBetweenDates(2015,6,1,2014,4,1)` and find that `print(new_month)` gives `106` and `print(nextDay(new_year,new_month,new_day))` gives `None`. Looking at the code block for `nextDay`, there is no condition to catch `month==106`, so the function returns the Python default of `None`.

While your values may vary, it appears that `new_month` is not in the set {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,22}, so the function is returning `None` and that is where your error is coming from. So you can either ensure that a tuple is always returned, or debug your code to see why you are getting input data different from those you have coded for.